# How Should I read CSV By Grouping Column of Same Value

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, apache-commons-csv

I have a task to read a CSV file then do some logic and then create a JSON for that.

I am kind of stuck with required logic before creating JSON, I need to set Max PR VALUE against the SK as PR for all the same SK's.

**My Requirement:**

**CSV:**

```
SK,VR,ST,PR
1000,1000-Q1,10,187
1000,1000-Q2,20,925  // MAX PR against SK
1001,1001-Q1,10,112
1001,1001-Q2,30,120  // MAX PR against SK
```

Note: Max PR against SK will always be in the last row of its SK.

I have to read CSV here and need to write JSON data as below :

```
[
   {
      "SK": "1000",
      "VR": "1000-Q1",
      "ST": "10",
      "PR": "925"
   },
   {
      "SK": "1000",
      "VR": "1000-Q2",
      "ST": "20",
      "PR": "925"
   },
   {
      "SK": "1001",
      "VR": "1001-Q1",
      "ST": "10",
      "PR": "120"
   },
   {
      "SK": "1001",
      "VR": "1001-Q2",
      "ST": "30",
      "PR": "120"
   }
]
```

**Edit:**

Code

```
       File input = new File("input.csv");
       File output = new File("output.json");
       CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder().setUseHeader(true).build();
       CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

       // Read data from CSV file
       List<Object> readAll = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(input).readAll();

       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

       // Write JSON formated data to output.json file
       mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(output, readAll);

       // Write JSON formated data to stdout
       System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(readAll));
```

Comment: I can not see the code that you have programmed

Comment: It's strongly recommended to provide [mcve] if you seek help at StackOverflow

Comment: @USM I proposed an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Approach would be to first group your CSV Records per **SK**

```
        String[] HEADERS = { "SK","VR","ST","PR"};

        Reader in = new FileReader("mycsvfile.csv");
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
          .withHeader(HEADERS)
          .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
          .parse(in);

        // Group the records by  SK
     Map<String, List<CSVRecord>> recordListBySK =   StreamSupport
            .stream(records.spliterator(), false).
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(record -> record.get("SK")));
```

Then you need to add another a Mapping this time, which keeps the **MAX-PR** per 
each *Sk*

```
 Map<String, Integer> skMaxMap =  recordListBySK
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors
                .toMap( e -> e.getKey(),
                        e -> e.getValue()
                              .stream()
                              .mapToInt(v -> Integer.parseInt(v.get("PR")))
                              .max()
                              .getAsInt() 
                      )
            );
```

Now you simply build you json *Sk* list like this:

```
 // Building the new sk (JSON ) objects
 List<NewSk> newSkList = new ArrayList<>();
 recordListBySK
    .values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(v -> v.stream())
    .forEach(csvRecord -> {
         NewSk newSk = new NewSk(csvRecord.get("SK"),
                                csvRecord.get("VR"),
                                csvRecord.get("ST"),
                                skMaxMap.get(csvRecord.get("SK"))
                                );
         newSkList.add(newSk);
    });
```

if you try to print them out:

```
newSkList.forEach(sk -> {
         System.out.print(" "+sk.getSk());
         System.out.print(" "+sk.getVr());
         System.out.print(" "+sk.getSt());
         System.out.print(" "+sk.getPr());
         System.out.println(" ");
     });
```

you'll get this

```
 1001 1001-Q1 10 120 
 1001 1001-Q2 30 120 
 1000 1000-Q1 10 925 
 1000 1000-Q2 20 925
```

No you can write your List to your JSON file using your JSON Object Mapper. 
Hope it helps

EDIT:

```
public class NewSk {

    private String sk;
    private String vr;
    private String st;
    private String pr;

    public NewSk(String sk, String vr, String st, String pr) {
        this.sk = sk;
        this.vr = vr;
        this.st = st;
        this.pr = pr;
    }

    public String getSk() {
        return sk;
    }

    public void setSk(String sk) {
        this.sk = sk;
    }

    public String getVr() {
        return vr;
    }

    public void setVr(String vr) {
        this.vr = vr;
    }

    public String getSt() {
        return st;
    }

    public void setSt(String st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

    public String getPr() {
        return pr;
    }

    public void setPr(String pr) {
        this.pr = pr;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is NewSk here? POJO?

Comment: NewSk is your simple POJO that would be used to write data to your json file

Comment: @USM did that help you ? if yes would consider accepting the answer? it would be nice.

Comment: @USM i made a last edit to the the second snippet to make sure that your PR first get converted from `String` to `Integer`, so that you can compute the `max` of your PR as `Integer`and not a `String`

Comment: Yeah, I Just noticed it. Can I change the Map<String, String> skMaxMap to Map<Object, Object>?

Comment: I updated again with  from `Map<String, String> skMaxMap ` to  `Map<String, Integer> skMap` and from `max()` to `max().getAsInt()`.

Comment: @USM your + 1 is enough, happy it could help !! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I've made a pojo to manipulate easily data :

```
public class Model {
    private final int sk;
    private final String vr;
    private final int st;
    private final int pr;

    public Model(int sk, String vr, int st, int pr) {
        this.sk = sk;
        this.vr = vr;
        this.st = st;
        this.pr = pr;
    }

    public int getSk() { return sk; }
    public String getVr() { return vr; }
    public int getSt() { return st; }
    public int getPr() { return pr; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model{" +
                "sk=" + sk +
                ", vr='" + vr + '\'' +
                ", st=" + st +
                ", pr=" + pr +
                '}';
    }
}
```

After, with Java 8 streaming you can do chat you want :

```
List<Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
models.add(new Model(1000, "1000-Q1", 10, 187));
models.add(new Model(1000, "1000-Q2", 10, 925));
models.add(new Model(1001, "1001-Q1", 10, 112));
models.add(new Model(1001, "1001-Q2", 30, 120));

List<Model> collect = models.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Model::getSk))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(
        v -> {
            int max = v.getValue()
                .stream()
                .map(m -> m.getPr())
                .reduce((a, b) -> Math.max(a, b))
                .get();
            return v.getValue().stream()
                .map(m -> new Model(m.getSk(), m.getVr(), m.getSt(), max));
        }
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(collect);
```

Result:

```
[
    {sk=1000, vr='1000-Q1', st=10, pr=925}, 
    {sk=1000, vr='1000-Q2', st=10, pr=925}, 
    {sk=1001, vr='1001-Q1', st=10, pr=120}, 
    {sk=1001, vr='1001-Q2', st=30, pr=120}
]
```